# activatedBackgroundIndicator on layout Android honeycomb

Tags: android, list, layout, background, android-3.0-honeycomb

I see that the new honeycomb has a gallery sample. 
and it shows you how to change the color of the selected text view by adding

```
android:background="?android:attr/activatedBackgroundIndicator"
```

to your textview

However my row for the list is not only a text view but a collection of views under a
linear layout .

To get the same behavior as the honeycomb gallery list selection  i tired to set the background of  this linear layout but it does not work. The selected row wont change color to blue.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:background=" android:attr/activatedBackgroundIndicator">
<BUNCH OF OTHER VIEWS/>
</LinearLayout>
```

thanks in advanced.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You forgot the `?` in the front of the `android:background` attribute value.

Also note that `activatedBackgroundIndicator` is only available in Android 3.0 and higher.

Comment: Hiii this worked for me thank you,can we change the background color from blue to some other color.

Comment: @dharan: Yes, via a style resource, though I do not have an example of doing this handy right now.

Comment: I was able to do this by writing a selector,for example                                                  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item name="android:activatedBackgroundIndicator" android:drawable="@color/orange_color" android:state_pressed="true"></item>
    <item android:drawable="@color/orange_color" android:state_activated="true"></item>

</selector>